# column values in excel to place the values (if any) in another column across the second row for a mailmerge word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have numerous columns in excel that I need to place the values (if any) in another column across the second row for that to pull on a mail merge to word.
If there a function I can place in the destination cells to extract any data if there are any.
I need the cells in the green area (DD2-DH2) to copy any values in the red area.
I hope the image helps. Also I need to let you know, usually there wont be more that 4 values in the red outlined area.
[image]

Comment: why not just a simple `cell dd2 -> '=cx2'`?

Comment: I think the opp wants dd2 to refer to the range CX2:DC11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the formula in cell DD2 and copy over:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($CX$2:$DC$11,COLUMNS($CX:CX)),"")
```

Adjust the range $CX$2:$DC$11 as needed.